# Fragment and view

Tags: java, android

My application is divided into fragments, each with its own layout (.xml file).

When I start visualize the first fragment in the `onCreate()` method of my activity, I set the appropriate layout with `setContentView(fragment_first)`. How do I change, for example, a `TextView` contained inside the second fragment (fragment_second)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a `Fragment`, or any `Activity` or `View` for that matter, should update its own internal UI controls.  It's easier, and it's good design.  Other classes/events may update the state of the `Fragment`'s data, but it handles how that state is displayed.

Edit to answer commented question:

This is how to load a content view in a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pump_info, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: ok, how do I create a class for that fragment and bind it so that I can load that layout when I'm on the fragment?

Comment: If this answer helped, you should mark it as the answer.  If you don't accept valid answers when people take the time to help you, people will be reluctant to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the xml file you intended for your first fragment in your activity.
What you should do in short is create a completely new class and have it extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, also have your activity extend FragmentActivity instead of just Activity.

Then in your `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class (which I shall call your fragment from now on) you should override the `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflate, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){}` method and in this method you should put a line like this:
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_xml_layout_for_this_fragment, container, false);` which inflates the layout of the fragment and plants it in the proper place in your activity's layout.

After this your need to `return view;`, but before you return this view you can do `view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_a_view_from_the_xml_layout_file);` in order to find an element and manipulate it.

You should create such a fragment class for each fragment you need in your app and have it inflate it's own xml layout file.

For more detailed instructions you can see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BKlST82Dtg or other videos or written tutorials.

EDIT: here is a basic fragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyFrag extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // inflate the view:
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfrag_layout, container, false);

    // manipulate widgets, for example:
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("read me!!!");

    // return the view:
    return view;
    }

}
```

and it's parenting activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // notice that there is a different layout file for the activity and for
    // the fragment!
    setContentView(R.layout.xml_layout_for_the_activity);

    // to start the fragment and stick it into your activity (not needed if
    // you use ViewPager)
    FragmentManager fragMan = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragMan.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.the_visual_element_that_will_contain_your_fragments_layout, fragMan)
        .commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: BTW you don't have to call your FragmentManager fragMan, I do it because it's funny. I won't tell you how I like to call my AssetManager's though. hehehe... XP

Answer (score 0):

in your `onCreateView()` method, you should assign all of the views you will need to access later to fields in your fragment class, like this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxx, container, false);

    this.aTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.a_text_view);
    this.anImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.an_image_view);
    ...
}
```

you can then use `aTextView`, etc. at other places in the execution of your fragment.